# column operation in csv [python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a scenario where I am extracting a row value from a csv file.

> (CSV) test1:

```
    Host, Time Up, Time Down, Time Unreachable, Time Undetermined
server1.test.com:1717,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
server2.test.com:1717,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
Average,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
```

> (CSV) test2:

```
Host,Service, Time OK, Time Warning, Time Unknown, Time Critical, Time Undetermined
server1.test.com:1717,application_availability_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,server_hit_rate,99.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,max_hit_rate,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,application_log_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,application_sessions_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
server2.test.com:1717,application_availability_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,server_hit_rate,99.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,max_hit_rate,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,application_log_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,application_sessions_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
Average,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
```

> This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test1.csv',skipfooter=1)
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv',skipfooter=1)
combined = pd.merge(df[['Host',' Time Up']],df2[['Host',' Time OK']], on='Host')
combined[' Time OK'] = combined[' Time OK'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
combined[' Time Up'] = combined[' Time Up'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
```

Here I am trying to get the value of "server_hit_rate" which is 99% & belongs to 3rd row data.
But with this above code I am able to get the data which is in first row only. i.e.

```
                    Host    Time Up    Time OK
0  server1.test.com:1717  100.000%   100.000% 
1  server2.test.com:1717  100.000%   100.000%
```

The required output should be:

```
                    Host    Time Up    Time OK
0  server1.test.com:1717  100.000%    99.000% 
1  server2.test.com:1717  100.000%    99.000%
```

Any advice to achieve the following will be helpful.

> Edit1:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas
import os, shutil, glob
import sys
import datetime
import time
def t1():
    import pandas as pd
    import pandas
    today=datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
    print "date :", today
    df = pd.read_csv('t1.csv',skipfooter=1, engine='python')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('t2.csv',skipfooter=1, engine='python')
    temp = df2.ffill()[df2['Service']=='server_hit_rate']
    combined = pd.merge(df[['Host',' Time Up']],temp[['Host',' Time OK']], on='Host')
    combined[' Time OK'] = combined[' Time OK'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
    combined[' Time Up'] = combined[' Time Up'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
    combined.to_csv('test.csv',index=False)
t1()


O/P:

Wed Nov 15 10:07:01  2017
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Host, % Time Up, % Time OK]
Index: []
```

Comment: Your data in `test2` appears to be all one long csv string (note that each row is beginning with a `,`. Is that supposed to be that way?

Comment: Yes Data is exactly the same

Comment: Well then those arent new rows. If it is all just 1 long string containing `,` (or even if it was a list) then you are only going to get 1 row.

Comment: Okay So is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Plent of ways, assuming you actually have rows of csv data. Your `test1` is valid, that is 4  rows of csv data (and by row, each ends with a `\n'). But in `test2`, notice how you really only have 2 rows. The first starts with `Host` the second with `Average`. Everything else in between is one giant csv row.

Comment: But when I view this data in CSV editor like (Microsoft excel) it shows me in proper row and column and there I could see that it belongs to 3rd row 3rd column

Comment: did you miss this line ?
"server2.test.com:1717,application_availability_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%"

Comment: your code works for me, i get two entries of `server_hit_rate`: `Host    Time Up    Time OK
0  server1.test.com:1717  100.000%   100.000%
1  server2.test.com:1717  100.000%   100.000%`

Comment: @downshift Can you check now , I believe you got 100% because the data "application_availability_check" which is in 2nd row has the same value 100%.
I have changed the values so it should come as 99.000% now

Comment: With the new data, I still get the same output https://i.imgur.com/WHNUQsm.png

Comment: @downshift expected is 99% what you have shows 100%.what you have done is for CSV1 but what I am talking about is CSV2, and the final data is combined with csv1 & csv2 where csv2 should extract data from row 3 & row 8 (according to this case , row number can vary with other data)under coloumn header Time OK

Comment: @pstatix Can you suggest something in this case how to extract the data

Comment: Is this acheivable ? Any sugesstion would be very much of help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be fairly simple if you select the data based on `Service` containing `server_hit_rate` by forward filling Host and then merge the data i.e

```
temp = df2.ffill()[df2['Service']=='server_hit_rate']

#                 Host          Service             Time OK      ...
#1  server1.test.com:1717  server_hit_rate  99.000% (100.000%)   ...
#6  server2.test.com:1717  server_hit_rate  99.000% (100.000%)   ...

combined = pd.merge(df[['Host',' Time Up']],temp[['Host',' Time OK']], on='Host')
combined[' Time OK'] = combined[' Time OK'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
combined[' Time Up'] = combined[' Time Up'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
```

Output of dataframe `combined` :

```
print(combined)

                  Host    Time Up   Time OK
0  server1.test.com:1717  100.000%   99.000% 
1  server2.test.com:1717  100.000%   99.000%
```

Also instead of using spaces before the column name strip the spaces using

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I checked the above code. It is not working.
Am I missing something here?
added the whole script in question.

Comment: Whats not working ? If you are gettin first row you should get this right

Comment: It doesn't generates the file first of all (test.csv).At the same time it doesn't gives an error too.

Comment: Could you add the output of `combined.head()` now? I thought the question was how to get the output? So next time do mention it that you want to export the output to csv.

Comment: `It doesn't generates the file first of all` - Check the directory you are saving the file to once, csv file is being generated when I try it in my machine.

Comment: Added o/p ...oops i got the file. but it doesn't have any data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159045/discussion-between-rebecca21-and-bharath).

Answer (score 0):

The DictReader tool in the csv library is handy for this sort of thing - it converts the column headings into dictionary keys, and then you can interrogate each row as you would any other dict.

```
from csv import DictReader

with open('test2.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    srcdat = DictReader(csvfile)
    csvdict = [line for line in srcdat]

for row in csvdict:
    if row['Host']:
        current_host = row['Host']
    q = row[' Time OK']
    q = q.split('.')[0]
    if int(q) <100:
        print(f'Host failure for: {current_host}')
        print('Time OK: ', row[' Time OK'])
```

the output isn't quite the format you want but should give you the foundation.

Comment: what exactly will this do ? i am reading two files. Are you doing something after the combined file?

Comment: sorry - I ran it against your second file but not the first, personally I'd turn it into a function or even a class and run it over each file in turn and then merge the answers rather than the whole files. the output is fairly inelegant but gets the answers you want: 

`Host failure for: server1.test.com:1717
Time OK:  99.000% (100.000%)
Host failure for: server2.test.com:1717
Time OK:  99.000% (100.000%)
Host failure for: Average
Time OK:  0.000% (0.000%)`

Comment: that wasn't my question about required output :-) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think this is slightly nicer code to get the results you want. Note I'm not retaining the "%" as you have indicated you want to select the larger of columns later. This way we convert to numbers and only use the columns we need, we also get rid of the annoying spaces in the column names from the beginning. By setting the index, we can get Pandas to line up the entries without calling merge.

```
def parse_percentage(perc_string):
    "Parse the percentage strings of the form 99.00% (99.00%)"
    return float(perc_string.split('%')[0])

t1 = pd.read_csv('t1.csv', 
                 skipfooter=1, 
                 engine='python',
                 sep=' *, *',  # This gets rid of the spaces
                 index_col='Host', 
                 usecols=['Host', 'Time Up'],
                 converters={'Time Up': parse_percentage})

t2 = pd.read_csv('t2.csv',
                  skipfooter=1, 
                  engine='python',
                  sep=' *, *',
                  usecols=['Host', 'Service', 'Time OK'],
                  converters={'Time OK': parse_percentage}).fillna(method='ffill').set_index('Host')

combined = pandas.concat([t1, t2[t2.Service == 'server_hit_rate']['Time OK']], axis=1)
combined.to_csv('test.csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used Python3.6.  Think this should give what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('t1.csv', skipfooter=1)
df1.columns = [c.strip() for c in df1.columns]
df2 = pd.read_csv('t2.csv', skipfooter=1)
df2.columns = [c.strip() for c in df2.columns]
df2 = df2.ffill()
combined = pd.merge(df1[['Host', 'Time Up']], df2[['Host', 'Service', 'Time OK']], on='Host')
combined['Time Up'] = combined['Time Up'].apply(lambda x : x.split('(')[0])
combined['Time OK'] = combined['Time OK'].apply(lambda x : x.split('(')[0])
print(combined[combined.Service == 'server_hit_rate'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your challenge was a nice coffee break in my day. See my code below. It works for both CSV1 and CSV2 files because I've made server-name and search-key variable for your search. For the learning-curve "# + comment" implemented where needed. No additional imports or whatsoever need. Just plain pythonic writing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# lists: csv1 and csv2 mimick reading from file.

csv1 =  ["Host, Time Up, Time Down, Time Unreachable, Time Undetermined",
         "server1.test.com:1717,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000",
         "server2.test.com:1717,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000",
         "Average,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000"]

csv2 =  ["Host,Service, Time OK, Time Warning, Time Unknown, Time Critical, Time Undetermined",
         "server1.test.com:1717,application_availability_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000",
         ",server_hit_rate,99.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000",
         ",max_hit_rate,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000",
         ",application_log_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000",
         ",application_sessions_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000",
         "server2.test.com:1717,application_availability_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000",
         ",server_hit_rate,99.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000",
         ",max_hit_rate,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000",
         ",application_log_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000",
         ",application_sessions_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000",
         "Average,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000"]

# assuming your provided data comes from a static file on hdd and can be read by using readline().

total_servers        = 2
count_server         = 0
current_server_name  = ''
result_dict          = {}

# added implementable server-number; just in case you got multiple servers as your example shows.
server_name = "server%s.test.com:"
search_key = ",server_hit_rate"

# the while-loop ploughs/iters through the file for a reason: > someone may have changed the order of servernames randomly.

while count_server < total_servers:
    for line in csv2:
    #    print line  # -> to check output on screen

        current_server_name = server_name % str(count_server + 1) # Some folks..start counting at "1"...

        if line.startswith((current_server_name)):
            print current_server_name

        if not line.startswith((search_key)):
            continue
        else:
#            print current_server_name
            print 'got your line of interest : "%s"' % line  # -> to check output on screen
            items = line.split(',')
            value = items[2]
            result_dict[current_server_name] = value

            count_server +=1

print result_dict
```

Enjoy!